# how can i fetch Gmail user Contact list in my Ios app using Api?

Tags: objective-c

i am trying to fetch Contact list of user after Login in gmail. i used  GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h and framework. i can fetch only user name, email .
so how to fetch user contact list using api or other way .

all steps from starting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'Retrieving all contacts' section at the [Google Contacts API guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

Comment: But how to authorise before calling api?

Comment: all steps from starting